# Using fat-free-framework fetch from table

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

How to fetch the all data from table using fat free

my code:

```
$user=new DB\SQL\Mapper($db,'test1');
$user->load()
```

But I want do display the all data without query.
I want to print the data using foreach statement

Answer (score 1):

## Solution with `Mapper`

The first solution exports `Mapper` data to an array before iterating the records.

```
$data = [];
$user = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'test1');

for ($user->load(); !$user->dry(); $user->next()) {
    $data[] = $user->cast();
}
```

Now it's possible to use `foreach($data as $user)` to iterate your users.

## Solution with `SQL`

It's also possible to fetch your records without a `Mapper` object.

```
foreach ($sql->exec('SELECT * FROM test1') as $user) {
    echo $user['name'];
}
```

## More information

Have a look at the documentation for more information and tips:

- http://fatfreeframework.com/sql#exec
- http://fatfreeframework.com/sql#pdo
- http://fatfreeframework.com/sql-mapper#cast

Comment: Thanks. i am having doubt. without fat-free framework i can use only sql fate free pdo concept on my project